# Select from "value" to "value"

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have this

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
```

and I want select from item *1* to item *5* and wrap them into an UL, and select *6* to *8* and wrapp them in another one.

```
<ul>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
</ul>


<ul>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
</ul>
```

How can I do that?. Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you want to invalidate perfectly good HTML? ;o)

Comment: just by location, or will you search the `.text`? Do you know they are sorted? What if the value isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

`<div>` is not a valid child element for `<ul>`. You should nest `<li>` elements. As for the selectors, you can use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
$('div.item:lt(5)').wrapAll("<div>");
$('div.item:gt(4)').wrapAll("<div>");
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm working with an old CMS and i need an ouput like that (by the way, i can't change how print HTML so i can't force semantic HTML, i do what i can xDD)

Answer (score 2):

To create *valid* HTML here you need to wrap them as list items as well, getting this result:

```
<ul>
  <li><div class="item">1</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">2</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">3</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">4</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">5</div></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><div class="item">6</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">7</div></li>
  <li><div class="item">8</div></li>
</ul>
```

Here's jQuery that will do that wrapping/grouping every 5 elements, and the remaining at the end, it'll work for any number of divs you have:

```
var elems = $("div.item");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=5) {
  elems.slice(i, i+5).wrap('<li></li>').parent().wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
}​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mX8bx/), this [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)s *each* element in a `<li>` then wraps the groups using [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) in `<ul>`.

Comment: +1 for the example, Nick.  I added a [quick update](http://jsfiddle.net/mX8bx/1/) using the selectors I gave in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083365/select-from-value-to-value/3083416#3083416).  Of course, yours is a little more flexible if there are going to be more than 10 elements divided into 5s.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you there...

```
$('div.item').slice(0, 5).wrapAll('<ul />');
$('div.item').slice(5).wrapAll('<ul />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is far from perfect, but for a start:

```
function findByText(n){
  return $('.item').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == n});
}

$(function(){
   var from = findByText(2);
   var to = findByText(5);
   $('.item').slice(from.index(), to.index() + 1).wrapAll('<div />');
});
```

It can be improved in many ways - you may want to convert `findByText` to a plugin that filters a collection, and you defiantly want to check `from` and `to`, and probably call `$('.item')` only once.
I think it's enough to get you going though.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ehite4/